# Robolectric: ClassCastException when passing Dagger modules as test parameter

Tags: java, android, junit, robolectric, dagger

I'm using Robolectric's `ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner` to spin up parameterized tests. For a subset of tests, I want to pass instances of Dagger modules as one of test parameter.

The code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class DummyTest {

    @Module
    static class AModule {}

    @ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                { new AModule() }
        });
    }

    private final Object module;

    public DummyTest(Object module) {
        this.module = module;
    }

    @Test
    public void should_do_smth() {
        ObjectGraph graph = ObjectGraph.create(module); <-- exception happens here
        graph.inject(this);
    }
}
```

When running this test, there's an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.test.DummyTest$AModule$$ModuleAdapter cannot be cast to dagger.internal.ModuleAdapter
    at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader$1.create(FailoverLoader.java:42)
    at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader$1.create(FailoverLoader.java:40)
    at dagger.internal.Memoizer.get(Memoizer.java:56)
    at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader.getModuleAdapter(FailoverLoader.java:57)
    at dagger.internal.Modules.loadModules(Modules.java:43)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.makeGraph(ObjectGraph.java:174)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.access$000(ObjectGraph.java:138)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph.create(ObjectGraph.java:129)
    at com.example.android.test.DummyTest.should_do_smth(DummyTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

The content of `DummyTest$AModule$$ModuleAdapter` is:

```
// Code generated by dagger-compiler.  Do not edit.
package com.example.android.test;

import dagger.internal.ModuleAdapter;

/**
 * A manager of modules and provides adapters allowing for proper linking and
 * instance provision of types served by {@code @Provides} methods.
 */
public final class DummyTest$AModule$$ModuleAdapter extends ModuleAdapter<DummyTest.AModule> {
  private static final String[] INJECTS = { };
  private static final Class<?>[] STATIC_INJECTIONS = { };
  private static final Class<?>[] INCLUDES = { };

  public DummyTest$AModule$$ModuleAdapter() {
    super(com.example.android.test.DummyTest.AModule.class, INJECTS, STATIC_INJECTIONS, false /*overrides*/, INCLUDES, true /*complete*/, false /*library*/);
  }

  @Override
  public DummyTest.AModule newModule() {
    return new com.example.android.test.DummyTest.AModule();
  }
}
```

How would I fix that?

Comment: Just wondering what are generated sources for `DummyTest$AModule$$ModuleAdapter`?

Comment: I believe it's already there? Just for reference, this question is related to Dagger 1.

Comment: I've updated the question with code generated for `ModuleAdapter`.

Comment: I looked to the code of Dagger class and Can not even guess where it fails :) I have only one guess that `Robolectric` is instrumenting classes and that causes CCE. Since dagger library is bundled with sources, can you put a breakpoint in this line and check types in debug?

Comment: Yep, I stepped through the code and compared how this `ModuleAdapter` is instantiated when passing module as parameter as opposed to just using the "new" operator. The only difference that I spotted is in class loaders. For the first case it's `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` and for the second - `org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader`. And for the first case casting fails, although in both cases instantiated module adapters are of type `DummyTest$AModule$$ModuleAdapter`.